# How to fix documentation warnings Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, warnings

E.g.

```
Orphaned Doc Comment Violation: A doc comment should be attached to a declaration. (orphaned_doc_comment)

/// Comment here - Warning comes over here
```

I am running Xcode 12.4. How to solve this warning or suppress this warning?

Answer (score 3):

You should attach the code block where this warning appears, but judging without too much context, it seems like you’re using SwiftLint, where the `orphaned_doc_comment` rule is enabled by default (read the docs [here](https://realm.github.io/SwiftLint/orphaned_doc_comment.html)).

Switching to a normal comment (just `//`) should resolve the issue. Otherwise, disable it in the `.swiftlint.yml` file.